# Perl replace first match after match

Tags: sed

I have this file:

```
host test-focal1.mydomain.local {
  hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
  fixed-address 192.168.10.10001;
  server-name "192.168.10.100";
  next-server 192.168.10.100;
  filename "pxelinux.0";
  option routers 192.168.10.1;
  option domain-name "mydomain.local";
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.10.100;
  option domain-search "mydomain.local";
  option host-name "test-focal1";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option root-path "/fai/nfsroot/focal,rsize=1048576,wsize=8192,acregmin=1800,acregmax=1800,acdirmin=1800,acdirmax=1800,vers=3,mountport=614,port=2049,proto=tcp,mountproto=tcp,mountvers=3,nolock,noacl";
  option option-170 "nfs://192.168.10.100/fai/config-focal";
  site-option-space "PXEL";
  option PXEL.magic xx:xx:xx:xx;
  option PXEL.configfile "pxelinux.cfg/fai-focal";
}

host test-jessie1.mydomain.local {
  hardware ethernet 00:50:56:bd:e7:78;
  fixed-address 192.168.10.10002;
  server-name "192.168.10.100";
  next-server 192.168.10.100;
  filename "pxelinux.0";
  option routers 192.168.10.1;
  option domain-name "mydomain.local";
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.10.100;
  option domain-search "mydomain.local";
  option host-name "test-jessie1";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option root-path "/fai/nfsroot/focal,rsize=1048576,wsize=8192,acregmin=1800,acregmax=1800,acdirmin=1800,acdirmax=1800,vers=3,mountport=614,port=2049,proto=tcp,mountproto=tcp,mountvers=3,nolock,noacl";
  option option-170 "nfs://192.168.10.100/fai/config-focal";
  site-option-space "PXEL";
  option PXEL.magic xx:xx:xx:xx;
  option PXEL.configfile "pxelinux.cfg/fai-focal";
}

host test-wheezy1.mydomain.local {
  hardware ethernet 00:50:56:bd:e7:79;
  fixed-address 192.168.10.10003;
  server-name "192.168.10.100";
  next-server 192.168.10.100;
  filename "pxelinux.0";
  option routers 192.168.10.1;
  option domain-name "mydomain.local";
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.10.100;
  option domain-search "mydomain.local";
  option host-name "test-wheezy1";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option root-path "/fai/nfsroot/focal,rsize=1048576,wsize=8192,acregmin=1800,acregmax=1800,acdirmin=1800,acdirmax=1800,vers=3,mountport=614,port=2049,proto=tcp,mountproto=tcp,mountvers=3,nolock,noacl";
  option option-170 "nfs://192.168.10.100/fai/config-focal";
  site-option-space "PXEL";
  option PXEL.magic xx:xx:xx:xx;
  option PXEL.configfile "pxelinux.cfg/fai-focal";
}
```

I need to replace by perl script `PXEL.configfile` option value only for a specific host,
for example for the host `test-focal1.mydomain.local` I need to set:

```
host test-focal1.mydomain.local {
  hardware ethernet 00:00:00:00:00:00;
  fixed-address 192.168.10.10001;
  server-name "192.168.10.100";
  next-server 192.168.10.100;
  filename "pxelinux.0";
  option routers 192.168.10.1;
  option domain-name "mydomain.local";
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.10.100;
  option domain-search "mydomain.local";
  option host-name "test-focal1";
  option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
  option root-path "/fai/nfsroot/focal,rsize=1048576,wsize=8192,acregmin=1800,acregmax=1800,acdirmin=1800,acdirmax=1800,vers=3,mountport=614,port=2049,proto=tcp,mountproto=tcp,mountvers=3,nolock,noacl";
  option option-170 "nfs://192.168.10.100/fai/config-focal";
  site-option-space "PXEL";
  option PXEL.magic xx:xx:xx:xx;
  option PXEL.configfile "pxelinux.cfg/test-focal";
}
```

I tried this code but doesn't work:

```
`sed -i '/host test-focal1/,/./ s/fai-focal/test-focal1/1' dhcpd.conf`;
```

What is the correct command?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with the command below:

```
`sed -i '/host $fqdn/,/fai-focal/ s/fai-focal/$fqdn/1' dhcpd.conf`;
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E '/host test-focal/{:a;N;/}$/!ba;s/fai(-focal)/test\1/}' file
```

Gather up lines between a line containing `host test-focal` and a line ending `}`, then replace `fai-focal` by `test-focal`.

Answer (score 2):

How about

```
perl -pi -e 's/fai-focal/test-focal1/ if /^host test-focal/ .. /^}/' infile
```

Using the [flip-flop operator](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop#Range-Operators).